# Colwise eats column names within ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to chunk through a data frame, find instances where the sub-data frames are unbalanced, and add 0 values for certain levels of a factor that are missing.  To do this, within ddply, I did a quick comparison to a set vector of what levels of a factor should be there, and then create some new rows, replicating the first row of the subdata set but modifying their values, and then rbinding them to the old data set.

I use colwise to do the replication.

This works great outside of ddply.  Inside of ddply...identifying rows get eaten, and rbind borks on my.  It's curious behavior.  See the following code with some debugging print statements thrown in to see the difference in results:

```
#a test data frame
g <- data.frame(a=letters[1:5], b=1:5)

#repeat rows using colwise
rep.row <- function(r, n){
  colwise(function(x) rep(x, n))(r)
}

#if I want to do this with just one row, I get all of the columns
rep.row(g[1,],5)
```

is fine.  It prints

```
  a b
1 a 1
2 a 1
3 a 1
4 a 1
5 a 1

#but, as soon as I use ddply to create some new data
#and try and smoosh it to the old data, I get errors
ddply(g, .(a), function(x) {

  newrows <- rep.row(x[1,],5)
  newrows$b<-0
  rbind(x, newrows)

})
```

This gives

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

You can see the problem with this debugged version

```
#So, what is going on here?
ddply(g, .(a), function(x) {
  newrows <- rep.row(x[1,],5)
  newrows$b<-0
  print(x)
  print("\n\n")
  print(newrows)
  rbind(x, newrows)

})
```

You can see that x and newrows have different columns - they differ in a.

```
  a b
1 a 1
[1] "\n\n"
  b
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

What is going on here?  Why when I use colwise on a subdata frame do the identifying rows get eaten?

Answer (score 2):

It's a funny interaction between ddply and colwise, it seems. More specifically, the problem occurs when `colwise` calls `strip_splits` and finds a `vars` attribute that was given by `ddply`.

As a workaround, try putting this first line in your function,

```
   attr(x, "vars") <- NULL
   # your code follows
   newrows <- rep.row(x[1,],5)
```